# How to read size of view?

Tags: swiftui

in Swift UI, I try to make a slider to control `value`(0…1), just like the original slider do.

I set up a rectangle with `offset` and `width`(the max offset) , and trying to link the `offset` with the `value`.

But the problem was, I use
`value = offset / width` ,
and I don’t know how to get the `width` of rectangle. In the code below, I set width as 320frames, but I want it to be programmatic, do anyone knows how? Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 50
    private let width: CGFloat = 320
    
    var value: CGFloat {
        offset / width
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: offset)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
        }
        .frame(width: width, height: 32)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/understanding-frames-and-coordinates-inside-geometryreader).